# Does .NET have an equivalent of **kwargs in Python?

Tags: python, .net, equivalent

I haven't been able to find the answer to this question through the typical channels.

In Python I could have the following function definition

```
def do_the_needful(**kwargs):
    # Kwargs is now a dictionary
    # i.e. do_the_needful(spam=42, snake='like eggs', spanish='inquisition')
    # would produce {'spam': 42, 'snake': 'like eggs', 'spanish': 'inquisition' }
```

I know .NET has the `ParamArray`, which produces a sequence of unnamed arguments, similar to the `*args` syntax in Python... Does .NET have an equivalent of `**kwargs`, or something similar?

Comment: Why exactly do you need them?

Comment: I only know the anonymous type hack where you write `do_the_neeful(new{spam=43})` and then extract the properties through reflection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, unfortunately, there is no way of simulating the Python `**kwargs` in C#. You will always loose parameter names in the process (see comment by [@alelom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3873799/alelom) below).

But, it seems that what you look for is a **variadic function**. If you want to know how to implement it in various programming languages, the best is to look at the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) about it.

So, according to the Wikipedia, implementing a variadic function in C# and VisualBasic is done like this:

> Other languages, such as C#, VB.net, and Java use a different
> approach—they just allow a variable number of arguments of the same
> (super)type to be passed to a variadic function. Inside the method
> they are simply collected in an array.
>
> #### C# Example
>
> ```
> public static void PrintSpaced(params Object[] objects)
> {
>     foreach (Object o in objects)
>         Console.Write(o + " "); 
> }    
> // Can be used to print: PrintSpaced(1, 2, "three");
> ```
>
> #### VB.Net example
>
> ```
> Public Shared Sub PrintSpaced(ParamArray objects As Object())
>     For Each o As Object In objects
>         Console.Write(o & " ")
>     Next
> End Sub
> ```
>
> ' Can be used to print: PrintSpaced(1, 2, "three")

Comment: C#/VB, and according to Wikipedia - nope, just the param only variety.

Comment: It's an equivalent of *args, not **kwargs.

Comment: Agree with @DmitriySintsov -- this answer is wrong, because `params` replicates the `*args` behaviour, not the `**kwargs` behaviour. You lose the parameter names with C#'s `params` keyword. From what I could gather, there is no built-in way to obtain the `**kwargs` behaviour in C# :(

Answer (score 0):

In vb.net, the pattern I've figured out is to create a method that converts a name value arg array to a OrderedDictionary and then in your function, accept the OrderedDictionary parameter as an argument. This would also work in c#.

```vb
Public Shared Function p2D(ParamArray args As Object()) As OrderedDictionary
    Dim kwargs As New OrderedDictionary
    For i As Integer = 0 To aNV.Length - 1 Step 2
        kwargs.Add(aNV(i), aNV(i + 1))
    Next
    Return kwargs
End Function
```

Usage:

```vb
Public Shared Sub do_foo(kwargs as OrderedDictionary)
  ' parse kwargs and do stuff...  
End Sub

' Call do_foo 
do_foo(p2D("arg1", 1, "arg2", 2, "arg3", 3))
```

With that said, its best to not program in VB at all as its a pretty bad language for doing anything of any real complexity and its OOP implementation is atrocious. When in doubt, use C#.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a more derived type for the `Object[]` parameter and use an array of `Tuple`, `KeyValuePair`, `record`, whatever e.g.:

```
    public static void PrintSpaced<TKey,TValue>(params (TKey, TValue)[] tuples)
    {
        foreach (var (key,value) in tuples)
            Console.Write(key + " " + value + Environment.NewLine); 
    }

    PrintSpaced((1, "Foo"), (2, "bar"));
```

Because of type inference you don't need to specify the generic parameters in the call, in other words `PrintSpaced<int,string>` is redundant.